# Getting failed requests with apache benchmark on a load balanced Tornado site but none logged

Tags: benchmarking, tornado, apachebench

Perhaps this is a question about ab rather than about Tornado but something doesn't make sense.

I run the benchmark like this:

```
$ ab -n 100 http://localdomainname/ # 2 tornados being 1 nginx
 ...
Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   0.162 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        17
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 17, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
```

So according to that 17 of 100 requests failed.

Prior to running the benchamark I reset the log files and look at them again:

```
$ wc -l /tmp/gkc.access.log 
100 /tmp/gkc.access.log
$ cat /tmp/gkc.access.log | grep ' 200 ' | wc -l
100
```

So, according to Nginx no requests failed! Why is ab saying 17 of 100 failed?

(By the way, 17 out of 100 was just one example. it goes up and down but never 0 which I'd expect)

UPDATE

Having tested with httperf without touching the Tornado+Nginx setup I get 0 failed requests.

Comment: Until I can figure this out I'm going with httperf

Comment: Tried this with a simple app, couldn't reproduce - bizarrely, I get connection reset errors with httperf, but only when I hit the file descriptor limit.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with Tornado´s `Hello world` example (412 of 10,000 requests failed, using ab, no nginx or other frontend).

Answer (score 14):

You get the "length" failed requests, which does not mean that the response code was not 200. It just means that the length of response across requests was different (it remembers the length of the first one).

In detail this issue has been discussed in this question: [Load Testing with AB ... fake failed requests (length)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579450/load-testing-with-ab-fake-failed-requests-length)