# error while running apache benchmarking from jenkins?

Tags: apachebench

Actually the developers when using the same tool locally all the requests are passing but when we are implementing it in our jenkins pipeline which is written in groovy the requests are failing .
Even I tried in local and its passing bt wen using jenkins pipeline after getting multiple :tart Time: 1613040130
16:12:10     Timeout   : 300 (sec)
16:12:10     Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
it says that after 10 failures test has been aborted.
Any resolution in this matter will be highly appreciated .
link to one of the stackoverflow channel:[Getting failed requests with apache benchmark on a load balanced Tornado site but none logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229489/getting-failed-requests-with-apache-benchmark-on-a-load-balanced-tornado-site-bu)

Comment: If you don't mind copying and pasting the exact error log that you're seeing from jenkins that might help others get more context into the issue itself coming from the application. Something that works locally and fails in a different environment can be a variety of things, though if I were to guess, it might have to do with Jenkins settings. Any relevant config file you can share for us to take a look?

Comment: Hi Gustavo: I figured out that its a version mismatch so I thought I will download  httpd24 which is actually running well but that I have to do without sudo so I pulled a container and tried installing httpd24 into it but  after 100 attempts and trying different commands it is not helping me its not getting installed am getting the message No package httpd24 is available. can you please advice on this issue

Comment: how is httpd24 related to the initial issue of benchmarking with Jenkins? just making sure it's related to the same issue and not a separate question. Shikha, to help you, we need more information such as logs, more context on the error message and setup you got going on. For instance, what application that had a version mismatch specifically? what kind of container are we talking about? if httpd24 is running well, what is not getting installed? these are some of the clarifications that if we could take a look at, might help solve your issue with Benchmarking from your Jenkins CI env.

Comment: Hi Gustavo. Thanks for reverting back.
let me explain the issue and the resolution too.I had the requirement of running the httpd24 in a centos7 conatiner with a hardened image and restrictive permission and this task was done usign declarative pipeline of jenkins. 
resolution: instead of httpd24 I used httpd24u as I only required apachebenchmark which I got using httpd24u-tools.

Comment: Coming to an other suggestion which I need . How can I pass the output of apachebenchmark which I get to telegraf and then to influxdb and eventually to grafana.