# Why doesn't Apache Bench work on google.com?

Tags: http, apachebench

```
$ curl -s -D - https://www.google.com/ -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 05:33:13 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=1111111111111111:FF=0:TM=1446096793:LM=1446096793:V=1:S=LVeGIvKogvfq6VHi; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-2015 16:02:17 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=72=sAIx-8ox3_AVxn6ymUjBsKzSmAXLwjNRTcV4Cj9ob1YmLkFc-lSJKvRK1kNdn1lIGruh-wH1_vctiRzKSFTG7IkJHSrVY_At_QbacsYgiI_8EOpMLe2cRIxXINj27DVpgnijGx7tKT1TCDirrunO3Bu0D4DVXz3lB0f42ZyJqOCtOJX2hprvbOOc8P8; expires=Fri, 29-Apr-2016 05:33:13 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
Alt-Svc: quic="www.google.com:443"; p="1"; ma=600,quic=":443"; p="1"; ma=600
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

but Apache Bench has errors for all but one request:

```
$ ab -n 5 https://www.google.com/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1528965 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking www.google.com (be patient).....done


Server Software:        gws
Server Hostname:        www.google.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,2048,128

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        18922 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   1.773 seconds
Complete requests:      5
Failed requests:        4
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 4, Exceptions: 0)
Total transferred:      99378 bytes
HTML transferred:       94606 bytes
Requests per second:    2.82 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       354.578 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       354.578 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          54.74 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      158  179  40.8    162     252
Processing:   132  176  79.0    148     316
Waiting:       81  118  80.5     83     262
Total:        292  354 119.5    310     567

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    299
  66%    321
  75%    321
  80%    567
  90%    567
  95%    567
  98%    567
  99%    567
 100%    567 (longest request)
```

Why does `ab` have errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `-l` to the command

It tells Apache Bench to not expect constant length for every response.
This should work:

```
ab -l -n 5 https://www.google.com/
```

Output:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1807734 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking www.google.com (be patient).....done


Server Software:        gws
Server Hostname:        www.google.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.2,ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305,256,256
TLS Server Name:        www.google.com

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        Variable

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   0.433 seconds
Complete requests:      5
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      67064 bytes
HTML transferred:       62879 bytes
Requests per second:    11.55 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       86.588 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       86.588 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          151.27 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       20   20   1.0     20      22
Processing:    63   66   2.7     67      69
Waiting:       62   65   2.8     66      68
Total:         83   86   3.3     87      91

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     85
  66%     89
  75%     89
  80%     91
  90%     91
  95%     91
  98%     91
  99%     91
 100%     91 (longest request)
```

Answer (score 1):

AB has categorized these as length errors because it expects the responses to be of the same length.  Google probably has some kind of dynamic content being returned on their homepage.

[Load Testing with AB ... fake failed requests (length)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579450/load-testing-with-ab-fake-failed-requests-length)